# Memory game show result after match

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to show result after match, but it compares after the third click event:

```
(this.aHracieTlactika[i] == e.getSource())
```

and I want to compare after the second click event.

```
    private int aPocitadlo = 1;
```

This is my method to check match of two arrays:

```
    public boolean zhoda() {
            if (this.aHodnotaTlac[0] == this.aHodnotaTlac[1]) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int pom = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.aHracieTlactika.length; i++) {

                if (this.aHracieTlactika[i] == e.getSource()) {
                    this.aHracieTlactika[i].setText("" + this.aHodnoty.get(i));
                    this.aHracieTlactika[i].setEnabled(false);
                    this.aPocitadlo++;
                    this.aPocetTahov += 1;

                    if (this.aPocitadlo == 3) {

                        if (this.zhoda()) {

                            this.aHracieTlactika[this.aTlacitkoIden[0]].setEnabled(false);
                            this.aHracieTlactika[this.aTlacitkoIden[1]].setEnabled(false);
pom += 1;    
  if (pom == 1) {
      System.out.println("You win");
                        }                             
                        } else {

                            this.aHracieTlactika[this.aTlacitkoIden[0]].setEnabled(true);
                            this.aHracieTlactika[this.aTlacitkoIden[0]].setText("");
                            this.aHracieTlactika[this.aTlacitkoIden[1]].setEnabled(true);
                            this.aHracieTlactika[this.aTlacitkoIden[1]].setText("");     
                        }

                        this.aPocitadlo = 1;

                    }

                     if (this.aPocitadlo == 1) {
                        this.aTlacitkoIden[0] = i;
                        this.aHodnotaTlac[0] = this.aHodnoty.get(i);
                    }

                    if (this.aPocitadlo == 2) {
                        this.aTlacitkoIden[1] = i;
                        this.aHodnotaTlac[1] = this.aHodnoty.get(i);
                    }  
            }
        }
```

Comment: May you please reformulate ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a global clickCount variable that you increment every time someone clicks the button. Then say if(clickCount % 2 == 0) which returns true when click count is divisible by 2.